Angular Production Build -> no output / 502 Error with nginx
I have updated to the latest Angular version and now have a main.server.mjs file instead of main.js.
I specified this in my pm2 ecosystem.config:
{
name : "angular_ssr",
instances: 1,
script : "/root/actions-runner/_work/dist/whoop/server/main.server.mjs",
autorestart: true
}

after a startOrRestart this instance is also shown as online. The nginx config has not changed:
server {
listen 80;
server_name whoop.com;
return 301 https://whoop.com/;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name whoop.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/whoop/bundle.crt;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/whoop/intermediate_whoop.com.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/whoop.com/whoop_com.key;
 include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
 ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

 error_log /var/log/error.log;
 access_log /var/log/access.log;

 location /api { rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1 break;
 proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 } location / { proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 5;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 4 32k;

gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
#gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].";
}

Unfortunately, I only get a "502 Bad Gateway" when I try to open the page.
What could be the reason for this - how can I debug the app as it is not logging ANY errors (not in pm2 logs and not in nginx)
When I run a node main.server.mjs I don't get any error messages.

Did you tried reading server error logs?

This question is similar to: Caprover nginx host mjs files. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It seems that the problem is caused by pm2 not being able to run the new server.ts configuration of 'angular 19'. I hope there will be a solution in the next pm2 release.
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/5921
https://stackoverflow.com/a/79222463/9576431

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
